# Ancel Keys and the 7 country study theories and/or evidence prior to 1961

Tags: nutrition

Is there any theory or evidence of saturated fat being bad for us prior to 1961 before Ancel Keys publish in Time Magazine "The 7 Country Study"?

I am just curious if there is anything out there that I have not already read.